# Stream video on display from server using NanoPi

Tags: communication, linux

I am working on a project where I am required to stream some videos hosted at the server onto a display connected to my NanoPi M1 plus via a HDMI cable. I have not a lot of knowledge about it. Which tools should I use for this? The video needs to start streaming after the NanoPi boots up. There should be no user input.

Comment: Hi Ron, can you elaborate a bit more about what you're doing, what your NanoPi setup is, what kind or at least amount and quality of video you're trying to stream and so on?

Comment: My NanoPi is simply connected to an ethernet cable and a display screen. I want the video to be streamed to be in HD or UHD quality. My atmost requirement is 4k streaming. Once my nanopi boots up, it should start streaming the video that it receives from the server onto the screen.